# More pixel PNG image can be smaller in size than lesser pixel image?

Tags: image, algorithm, compression, png

I have the following png images (both created by cropping out of screenshots of a desktop screen, using same software) :

280x261 : 79.4 KB

[image]

380 x 354 : 3.62 KB

[image]

I am confused. Shouldn't it take more bits to store the <strike>meta</strike> information about larger number of pixels than lesser number of pixels ?

Comment: You can learn about image compression basics from wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression

Comment: How is meta information even involved? You're asking about the actual information, right?

Comment: @harold You are correct, edited that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PNG format uses lossless compression, meaning that the operation if fully reversible.

It relies among others on Huffman coding, such that frequent colors are coded with less bits, and duplicate string elimination. So images with a "simpler" content can compress better.

**Added by Mark Setchell**

Just to illustrate Yves' answer... if you take your urn image and make all the non-white pixels black like this:

```
convert urn.png -fill black +opaque white blackurn.png
```

[image]

the file is now just 894 bytes:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff     894 19 Feb 11:08 blackurn.png
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind my editing your post - but I don't want to compete and steal points from a perfectly good answer!